# 8 pin aux audo cable into cd-changer port on radio?

Tags: audio, car

I have a VOD Dayton MS 4150 car radio:
http://www.manualslib.com/manual/185772/Vdo-Dayton-Ms-4150-Rs.html?page=4#manual
with a 8-pins CD changer port (C3 on the manual). The radio does not have an aux function. 
[image]

What I want is to connect my phone with an aux cable to the radio.. what i've found so far is this;
http://www.ycarlink.com/pd_10533_Car-MP3-WMA-Integration-kit-for-Renault-Siemens-VDO-Dayton-8-pin-USB-SD-AUX-Bluetooth-adapter-.htm
[image]
However that's a complete digital USB/aux package, quite expensive. It says on that page it will be able to fit into the CDC port of that specific radio. 
something like $80

However I was just wondering.. if I could use something like this:
Just a regular 3.5mm audio jack - 8 pins cable to the CDC port and if that will work (or not)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *might* be able to use something like this, but there are trade-offs.

The "kit" you show is plug-n-play. You'll have to repin the 3.5mm cabling to allow you to utilize it, unless you can find one which will work specifically with your system.

The only thing you'll be able to do with the 3.5mm cable is pipe audio through it. With the "kit", you should be able to control your device directly from the car stereo. Getting the kit would allow you to control things "hands-free", especially if you have steering wheel controls.

Cost is one thing, but ease of use and installation can make up for a lot of the difference.

Comment: Well for $4 i can imagine I won't be able to control it, but that's ok.. the only thing I want is indeed to pipe music trough it from my phone. You're saying I'll have to rewire it though? So (maybe?) remove the blue/red/yellow cables in the blue plug and rewire them for where they need to go (aren't these ISO plugs?). I'm still not quite sure if you meant to say that it WILL work piping music trough it, however for the controls to work i'll have to rewire it.. or that you meant to say even for just playing music controlling it from my phone i will have to rewire as well.. ?

Comment: If you get a 3.5mm plug which is specifically designed to plug into your head unit, you'll be able to pipe music into it, but will not be able to control the music through the head unit. If you get a generic one (like the one you have shown above), you'll have to rewire it into a new plug in order to get it to work. The one you have pictured does not have the right connection (so am assuming it is a generic picture).

Comment: THnx Paulster2, doesnt have the right connection? In the first picture the C3 plug is 8 pins, square (kind of), the generic one as well; they seem to be of the same kind, or do you mean the yellow/red/white wires that go into the blue plug are wired in a different order for it to work?

Answer (score -1):

you can use that cheap aux adapter only if you have ''update list'' tuner. If you have ''tuner list'' HU only CD changer emulator adapter is possible. Like Yatour